# RPG - what is += here?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

Can you explain what the `+=` means in this statement?

```
Eval      AssGr2Pun += FinQty#
```

Here is the rest of the code for context:

```
 Exsr      FinItmTot                 
 Eval      AssGr2Pun += FinQty#      
 If        OrderAdd = 'N'            
 Eval      Gr2TPass += 1             
 Eval      OrderAdd = 'Y'            
 Endif                               
 Eval      AssGr2Pst += 1            
 When      OhReqd = Today            
 Exsr      FinItmTot                 
 Eval      AssGr2Tun += FinQty#      
 If        OrderAdd = 'N'            
 Eval      Gr2TTday += 1             
 Eval      OrderAdd = 'Y'            
 Endif                               
 Eval      AssGr2Tod += 1            
 When      OhReqd = Tomorrow         
 Exsr      FinItmTot
```

Comment: if that's anything like most other languages that use `+=`, then `x += 1` is the equivalent of `x = x + 1`

Comment: It means to add and assign in a single operation. `X += 4` is the same as `X = X + 4`.

Comment: `+=` does not seem to be in any of the RPG language references.

Comment: but they are using it so it must be somewhere

Comment: For current reference information regarding IBM i, please refer to the [IBM i Knowledge Center](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/welcome.html?lang=en) as illustrated in JamesA's correct answer.

Comment: _Almost_ funny -- "current reference". It's been about eight years since the operator was made part of the language. (I'm pretty sure @WarrenT knows that.) It was one of the V5R2 incremental changes. V5R3 brought the full refresh of the ILE RPG compiler, including new manuals/documentation. It's been documented ever since... which is where the answer probably should be found.

Comment: My comment was responding to those who said they couldn't find it in a reference, and did not know where they were looking. RPG II runs on other systems. And I have watched others merely try looking in the first few Google results, which sometimes sent them in odd directions, when it would have paid off to simply keep the Info Center bookmarked.

Comment: @WarrenT Understood and agreed, which is why it's only "almost" funny". RPG II/III are always possibilities without explicit mention. The use of `+=`, though, generally accompanies code with multiple elements that wouldn't exist in RPG II/III not to mention the basic format of the statements themselves. The EVAL statement alone (whether explicit or implicit) is not part of RPG II/III. And if confusion with RPG II/III is the problem, then it becomes "_almost_ sad" since RPG IV is now **20** years old.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an [assignment operator](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzasd/sc092508797.htm%23expropt?lang=en).

Where <*target*> <*assignment operator*> <*expression*>:

- = The expression is assigned to the target
- += The expression is added to the target
- -= The expression is subtracted from the target
- *= The target is multiplied by the expression
- /= The target is divided by the expression
- **= The target is assigned the target raised to the power of the expression

Answer (score 1):

This operator is useful with char varying variables as well.
D wVar        S         32740a    Varying
 /Free
   wVar='My name';
   wVar+=' is';
   wVar+=' Charly';
   *INLR = *On;
 /End-Free
Of course it's just an example to show this capability.